# Capture the first time the geolocation is requested to the user

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm building a service to record website visitors geolocation using the HTML5 geolocation API. The problem is that I want to record only the first time the visitor give permission to the geolocation API. The API provides the following method to retrieve the location:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(saveToDatabase);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
```

But if I save the location inside the saveToDatabase function I'm going to record every time this is requested, not when the user give permission.

I expect I can save the first geolocation requested to the user. Anyway I can accomplish this?

Comment: First, you need to check the DB if the location is already saved,IF Yes, use the saved location. ELSE, call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(saveToDatabase)`

Comment: A number of ways. Have you had anything in mind? Have you tried anything? It depends on your system, too. What if you user changes location between visits? Does the application use a database? Does it support user sessions? What about setting a flag in a cookie or LocalStorage? The question is too broad in this form.

Comment: There is no session because visitors are not logged in. I thought on compare the location to the database if it already exists but coordinates can change every time. Also store a cookie or use LocalStorage can be a solution, but if the user cleans this information I will be recording his location multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var date = null;

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
   if (date != null) {
       date = Date.now();
   }
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(saveToDatabase);
 } else {
   x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }
```

Comment: What if the page is reloaded?

Comment: You could store it in a cookie and check if cookie exists instead of checking if date is null

Comment: Indeed you could. Your answer doesn't indicate anything like that though and has no explanation whatsoever. Not a good answer.

Comment: You didn't mention the page being reloaded in your question